# How to convert certificate and key .pem files to java keystore for use in Android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, keystore, x509, aws-iot

I am fairly new to Android development. Sorry if this is a basic question. I have already made my AWS IoT Certificate and attached to it the corresponding IoT Policy and IoT Thing I am trying to connect to. I got a certificate made by AWS and it gave me three .pem files to download: the certificate and the private and public keys. It also gave me the RootCA1 and RootCA3 certificates.

In the [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/pubsub/working-api/q/platform/android/), it says that we can connect to AWS using the certificate with

```
mqttManager.connect(<YOUR_KEYSTORE>, new AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(final AWSIotMqttClientStatus status,
                                final Throwable throwable) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Status = " + String.valueOf(status));
    }
});
```

and from [here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/iot/AWSIotMqttManager.html) we get that the argument `<YOUR_KEYSTORE>` is a `java.security.KeyStore` object. How can I make this object given the files I have from AWS IoT?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [AWSIotKeystoreHelper.saveCertificateAndPrivateKey API](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/iot/AWSIotKeystoreHelper.html#saveCertificateAndPrivateKey-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.security.PrivateKey-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), which can create a keystore file from a private key and a certificate.